# AWS problems: copy a large file in the same bucket but in different folder

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, multipart-upload

i have a problem with a lambda function, here the problem:
my lambda function needs to handle a PutObject event:

When the PutObject is managed, I have to copy the large file uploaded to the same bucket but to a different folder.

I tried with s3.copyObject (), with s3.PutObject () and with createMultipartUpload () [implementing the whole loop to handle this function: uploadPart, etc ...] but nothing worked!

The event is captured but subsequently the function does not print anything in the console, neither failure nor success.

Here the lambda:

```
    // dependencies
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const util = require('util');
const fs = require('fs');

// get reference to S3 client
const s3 = new AWS.S3();

const uploadPart = (params, chunk, partno, final, cb) => {
  console.log("##### Upload part: ", partno);
  s3.uploadPart({
    Body: chunk,
    Bucket: params.Bucket,
    Key: params.Key,
    UploadId: params.UploadId,
    PartNumber: partno
  }, (err, res) => {
    if (err) { console.log('## Errore: failed part uploaded: ', err); return; }
    if (cb) cb(null, { size: chunk.length, ETag: res.ETag });
  });
};

const completeMultipartUpload = (params, PartMap) => {
  console.log("##### 4. INIT COMPLETE MULTIPART UPLOAD");
  s3.completeMultipartUpload({
    Bucket: params.Bucket,
    Key: params.Key,
    UploadId: params.UploadId,
    MultipartUpload: PartMap
  }, (err, data) => {
    if (err) { console.log('## Errore: failed complete multipart upload: ', err); return; }
    console.log('###### 5. Upload completed: ', JSON.stringify(data));
  });
};

exports.handler = async (event, context, callback) => {

  // Read options from the event parameter.
  console.log("Reading options from event:\n", util.inspect(event, {depth: 5}));
  
  const srcBucket = event.Records[0].s3.bucket.name;
  const srcKey    = decodeURIComponent(event.Records[0].s3.object.key.replace(/\+/g, " "));
  const maxchunksize = event.Records[0].s3.object.size;
  const dstBucket = "bucketsrctest";
  
  console.log("SRC KEY: ", srcKey, ", File Size: ", ((maxchunksize / 1024) / 1024), " MB");

  // Infer the file type from the file suffix.
  const typeMatch = srcKey.match(/\.([^.]*)$/);
  if (!typeMatch) {
      console.log("Could not determine the file type.");
      return;
  }

  // Check that the file type is supported
  const fileType = typeMatch[1].toLowerCase();
  if (fileType != "csv") {
      console.log(`Unsupported file type: ${fileType}`);
      return;
  }
  
  const URI_PARTS = srcKey.split('/');
  const TOTAL_PARTS = URI_PARTS.length;
  
  const pre_file_folder = URI_PARTS[TOTAL_PARTS - 2];
  const hour = URI_PARTS[TOTAL_PARTS - 3];
  const day = URI_PARTS[TOTAL_PARTS - 4];
  const month = URI_PARTS[TOTAL_PARTS - 5];
  const year = URI_PARTS[TOTAL_PARTS - 6];
  const sub_folder = URI_PARTS[TOTAL_PARTS - 7];
  const main_folder = URI_PARTS[TOTAL_PARTS - 8];
  
  console.log("PATHS: ", URI_PARTS);
  
  const dst = prepareData(main_folder);
  
  try {
          const finalDestinationPath = dst.folder + '/' + (dst.subfolder ? dst.subfolder + '/' + dst.renamedFile : dst.renamedFile);
          
          const params = {
              Bucket: srcBucket,
              CopySource: srcKey,
              Key: finalDestinationPath
          };
          
          console.log("####1. INITIALIZE UPLOAD: ", finalDestinationPath);
          
            s3.createMultipartUpload({
            Bucket: dstBucket,
            Key: srcKey,
            ContentType: 'text/csv'
          }, (err, data) => {
            console.log("##### 2. INIT MULTIPART UPLOAD");
            if (err) { console.log('## Errore: failed create multipart upload: ', err); return; }
            const file = fs.createReadStream(finalDestinationPath);
            let pi = 1;
            let partMap = [];
            let streamedLength = 0;
            let uploadedSize = 0;
            let curchunk = Buffer(0);
            
            const cmuParams = {
              Key: srcKey,
              Bucket: dstBucket,
              UploadId: data.UploadId
            };
            
            const Writable = require('stream').Writable;
            const ws = Writable();
            
            ws.oend = ws.end;
            ws.end = (chunk, encoding, callback) => {
              ws.oend(chunk, encoding, callback);
              uploadPart(cmuParams, curchunk, pi, true, (err, data) => {
                partMap.push({ ETag: data.ETag, PartNumber: pi });
                completeMultipartUpload(cmuParams, { Parts: partMap });
              });
            };
            
            ws._write = (chunk, enc, next) => {
              curchunk = Buffer.concat([curchunk, chunk]);
              streamedLength += chunk.length;
              if (curchunk.length > maxchunksize) {
                uploadPart(cmuParams, curchunk, pi, false, (err, data) => {
                  uploadedSize += data.length;
                  partMap.push({ ETag: data.ETag, PartNumber: pi });
                  pi+=1;
                  curchunk = Buffer(0);
                  next();
                });
              } else {
                next();
              }
            };
            
            file.pipe(ws);
          });
  } catch(err) {
    console.log("Result error: ", err);
    return { statusCode: 500, body: err };
    }
};
```

Comment: To clarify, are you saying that you're not seeing any response - whether positive or negative - from your function? Have you checked the monitoring on the function to ensure that it's not timing out? Cloudwatch logs should provide some indication as to what's happening.

Comment: Did you check cloudwatch logs for any errors ?

Comment: Here the log:

`2022-09-12T09:07:31.967Z 08b575df-9a05-4016-b6cc-4a43b6c2b699 INFO ####1. INITILIAZE UPLOAD:  IS_EVENTS/IsEvents.csv
END RequestId: 08b575df-9a05-4016-b6cc-4a43b6c2b699
REPORT RequestId: 08b575df-9a05-4016-b6cc-4a43b6c2b699 Duration: 658.05 ms Billed Duration: 659 ms Memory Size: 128 MB Max Memory Used: 77 MB Init Duration: 467.90 ms`

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

This probably happens because you are using [async lambda handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async). Thus your function completes, before the body of your handler actually executes.

To fix that, you either have to modify your code to use [sync handler](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-sync), or use [promise pattern](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/nodejs-handler.html#nodejs-handler-async) shown in AWS docs for async handler.

Comment: Ok thank you, i solve the async issue, but now i have another problem. 
Here: 
`"stack": [
        "Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'root/........../prefolder/test2.csv'"
    ]`

Comment: @AntonioLongo This is a new issue thus new question should be asked.